# Browser video playback issue: How do I fix the flickering videos in GNOME and MATE?

Tags: gnome, video, display, screen, 17.04

Apologies if the title of the post was a little frenetic. Basically, I have this weird issue of video playbacks (youtube, watchseries etc.) in browsers (I have tested with Firefox, Firefox Nightly and Chrome) flickering from time to time. If I have the video running in windowed mode, only the video portion of the screen will (occassionally) have a horizontal flicker. The rest of the screen remains normal though. Usually happens once every 7-10 mins.

I would have pegged it for a driver issue, but (a) I am running the latest drivers for both intel an Nvidia (GTX 970M) cards, and (b) the problem only occurs in Gnome and Mate desktops! I have tested Ubuntu Unity (17.04 and 16.04), Ubuntu Gnome, Ubuntu Mate (same versions), and Linux Mint 18.2 Mate and Cinnamon. Across both only Mate and Gnome replicates the issue. Cinnamon and Unity do not! Problem is I can't stand either, and I can't live without the Gnome experience.

Any ideas as to what could be the issue, or even a possible fix, would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem occur on both Intel and Nvidia adapters? Did you install the Nvidia driver from the Ubuntu repos, or the Nvidia web site? What happens if you try the lightdm display manager? `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

Comment: The issue is persistent across both GPUs, yes! And I am using the proprietary Nvidia drivers available within the Ubuntu Driver Manager.

I am not sure how to switch to lightdm. Also, isn't that primarily supposed to be about the login screen?

Comment: Yes, lightdm will change your login screen, but it'll also change the display manager that's used to display your screen. I recently switched from lightdm to gdm3, as I wanted the full GNOME experience, but found that it flickers on occasion. To switch back to gdm3, use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`. You might try switching from the proprietary Nvidia driver to the one from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: I will look up the information on switching to lightdm! Thanks for the explanation!

I would, in fact, normally use the nouveau drivers (as a matter of principle). But I have been doing some graphic intensive fMRI stuff, and the image processing really works better with the Nvidia drivers (especially with the GTX 970M).

But usually my laptop is always on the intel GPU (unless I am using fMRI inputs), and the video flickering issue is present in this mode too!  Also, normal video player based videos don't flicker. Nor does the screen, unless it's playing some within-browser video.

Comment: To test with lightdm, use the command that I gave in my earlier comment... but yes, please do research it to understand it all. See `man dpkg-reconfigure` for some help. Oh, I misunderstood... if the problem occurs on both Intel and Nvidia, the Nvidia drivers aren't the problem. Since you say it's only occurring with the browser, either temporarily disable extensions for that browser, or test it with another browser.

Comment: I have switched to lightdm, and am currently testing it out. I have been running lightdm within the Gnome on Wayland session! While the video flickering issue has definitely been less frequent since the switch, there's still the occasional flicker. I will test it out for another day, then a couple days on Gnome Default, and post the update here.

Comment: Okay, I can now confirm that this issue is replicable in lightdm too. Also, with lightdm it seems to be more readily recurrent in Gnome Default sessions than in Gnome on Wayland.